# Busqueda binaria, devolucion de todos los elementos de un array que son iguales

Tags: java, array

La busqueda binaria siempre me devuelve el primer elemento que es igual al que buscamos, pero como podriamos hacer para que te devolviera las posiciones de todos los elementos que son iguales al que buscamos, por ejemplo, tenemos  un vector de:

H-H-J-O

si utilizo una busqueda binaria buscando H me dira que la H esta en la posicion 0 obviando la segunda que se encuentra en la posicion 1, hay alguna manera de adaptar la busqueda para que te devuelva la posicion de todos los elementos? En este caso la salida seria, la H se encuentra en la posicion 0 y en la posicion 1 
gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrías utilizar un HashMap si sabes lo que es, en este guardarías la letra en la posición en la que está

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpleemtne lo que tienes que hacer es que la forma de obtener las posiciones, en vez de devolverte un numero solo, te devuelva más de un número.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] vectorCaracter = new char[4];

        vectorCaracter[0] = 'H';
        vectorCaracter[1] = 'H';
        vectorCaracter[2] = 'J';
        vectorCaracter[3] = 'O';

        char valorBusqueda = 'H';

        List<Integer> listaPosiciones = obtenerPosiciones(vectorCaracter, valorBusqueda);

        for (Integer posicion : listaPosiciones) {
            System.out.println("El caracter "+ valorBusqueda + " se encuentra en la posicion " + posicion);
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }

    private static List<Integer> obtenerPosiciones(char[] vectorCaracter, char valorBusqueda) {
        List<Integer> listaPosiciones = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < vectorCaracter.length; i++) {
            if (vectorCaracter[i] == valorBusqueda) {
                listaPosiciones.add(i);
            }
        }

        return listaPosiciones;
    }

}
```